# Как определить позицию регулярного выражения?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Есть строка. Одна строка. И в этой строке куча всего, всяких там буковок и циферок и символов.

Есть регулярное выражение (оно может быть любым).

И есть число, это число какая-то позиция в нашей строке.

И надо узнать, находится ли наша позиция в пределах нашего регулярного выражения.
Наведите на мысль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно еще так:

```
s="some text some TEXT";
re=/text/ig;
pos=9;
function getpos(s, re, pos){
     var d=null;
     while((d=re.exec(s))!= null) {
         if (pos>= re.lastIndex-d[0].length && pos<re.lastIndex) {
              re.lastIndex=0;
              return true;
         };
    };
    return false;
};
test="";
for (i=0; i<s.length; i++) if (getpos(s, re, i)) test+="1"; else test+="0";
alert(test); // 0000011110000001111
```

**UPD**: убран костыль, добавлены вары и наглядный тест, исправлена ошибка множественного вызова функции.

Comment: скольких `var`'ов не хватает?

Comment: трех :) []()

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
var position = 13,
    string = '...',
    regexp = /.../gi,
    result = regexp.test(string.substring(position, 1));
```

Оборачиваем в функцию...PROFIT!

- [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)
- [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но если у нас в регулярном выражении есть что-то типа (begin|end) а строка begin и позиция 3, то такой вариант не пойдет.

Comment: вы хотели наводку на мысль - вы её получили, или хотите чтобы я реализовал все нюансы=)

>в регулярном выражении есть что-то типа (begin|end) а строка begin и позиция 3

а зачем тогда позиция? проверяйте всю строку, или хотя бы позицию выражайте 2-ми параметрами - началом и концом.